# Receiving DATA from FIREBASE in inbuilt ( Android Studio ) Emulator But Not in APP or if opening with other Emulator No database is Shown

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, wallpaper

Building an application:
Tool: `ANDROID STUDIO 22`
Language: `kotlin`
Database: Firebase

I'm receiving images from firebase realtime database. Everything works fine in Standard Emulator (Pixel 6 API 29)
All Code are added via image click on the below topics to preview the cod

iam using the cloud firestore for data required

But images are not receiving in real phone or other Emulators like **BlueStack** or **Geny Motion**.

I have set up all the permissions and sdk of firebase too but not working. Even I have included `SHA-1` and `SHA-256` certificates in firebase console.

Comment: Add some code for us to verify

Comment: Are you using the same signing key for all tests? It could be that it works with your debug key but not with the release key because you only added the signature of the debug key to the firebase console.

Comment: maybe i cant conform i checked can you tell how can we do that

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: sure thank you for your tip as i am new to this its help a lot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.